# The server method xxx failed (asp.net ajax)

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I have a website project, that is working fine. However every once a while certain ajax pages (that make calls to a webservice) throw a "the server method xxx failed". I have ELMAH installed, however do not see any stacktrace or anything. The worst is that I can not reproduce the error locally. I just get an email notification from ELMAH. Does anybody know how I can fix this issue?

Edit: After 1 year I am still having the same issue.

Comment: Note if you have this error and are using url rewriting, see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4321240/pagemethod-and-url-rewrite

Answer (score 1):

It's too insufficient description. My assumptions:

- Did you add `EnablePageMethods
  ="true"` to your `ScriptManager` control?
- If yes, did the control (if it is; e.g. button) which call the web service method perform an anync postback instead of full one?
- Does the signature of server method
  and a call from the client-side
  match?
- Are you using URL rewriting?

Comment: No, I did not add EnablePageMethods. I am using a webservice. 
Yes, the signature and call do match. As said this happens every once a while. No, I am not using any url rewriting.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and found my application firewall was blocking the content-type 'application/json'.  Check if you have anything running on the web server that could be blocking the page method.

Answer (score -1):

I happened the same with ASP.NET, **remove** the property `runat="server"` and run success